# Dynamics CRM 2013: Accessing Billable Time on Case Resolution Entity

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have a couple of things I'm trying to do:

1.) Create a workflow that updates a task's duration from a case's billable time resolution

2.) Run a report on Billable time or billable time vs other activities

The main issue that I'm having is that I can't seem to pull the billable time (time spent) field in any report or workflow. For whatever reason there's a separate entity from the case entity (Case Resolution) that contains this data however it seems uncustomizable and virtually invisible.

Anybody have ideas?

Comment: Om sure a lot of people have ideas, but please show what you have done so far, where you are having an issue, and where exactly you need help

Comment: Case Resolution is a type of activity. For reporting you can query that (`FilteredActivityPointer` using SSRS). As for item #1, this seems backwards as billable time rolls up from activity durations linked to cases...

Comment: @Pseudonym What I've done so far is create a workflow that automatically creates a case based off of a category specified for a task, autofilling most of the category info. What I want to do is once the case has been resolved, to have it automatically update the tasks duration based off of what the person who resolved the case entered in for billable time.

Comment: @JasonFaulkner We don't have access to the backend of CRM since upgrading to 2013, so everything I'm doing has to be done through the front end.

Comment: @Mr.Irrelevant - You are going to be pretty limited then if you can't run SSRS reports.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a report using the Report Builder, which will allow you to create a report linking Cases and Case Resolutions.

See here: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/survivingcrm/archive/2014/04/09/accessing-special-activity-data-with-crm-report-wizard.aspx